# Why a python websockets client resets a connection every 50 seconds?

Tags: websocket, python-3.8

Error with the python `websockets` client. Every ~50 seconds the client resets the connection.
The Server showing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 133, in websocket_endpoint
    await Importer(websocket).start()
  File ".\main.py", line 127, in start
    await self.receive_data(await self.websocket.receive_json())
  File "C:\python\env\py38\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 98, in receive_json
    self._raise_on_disconnect(message)
  File "C:\python\env\py38\lib\site-packages\starlette\websockets.py", line 80, in _raise_on_disconnect
    raise WebSocketDisconnect(message["code"])
starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect: 1006
```

The client doesn't show anything errors.

The Server on FastApi running with help `uvicorn`.

```
uviconr main.app --reload --ws websockets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Websockets` is asynchronous and if exist blocking of the thread more 50 seconds how in my case then the connection resets. For fix this need find functions which block thread and run their with help:

```
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_io_function)
```